# JS focusable div prevent body scroll on keyup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a focusable div that I want catch keyup events and prevent the body from scrolling when the user presses arrow down or arrow up. I call  `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` but it's not working.

```js
$('div').click((e) => e.focus())

$('div').on('keyup', (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div tabindex="0">Hey</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only [`keydown`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event without `focus`

Also add if the key that press is `40` whats mean `arrow down`

```js
$('div').keydown(function(e) {
if(e.which==40){
    e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div tabindex="0">Hey</div>
```